# JSP submits the form even though js returns false

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to validate a form. Simply trying to confirm the passwords. JS shows the alert and the function return false however it still submits the form to the next page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script>
        function validatePassword(){
            var password=document.form1.password.value;
            var cpassword=document.form1.cpassword.value;
            if(password!=cpassword){
                alert("Password Do not match");
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="validatePassword();" action="login.jsp">
        <table width="80%">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;width:40%">Password<font color="red">*</font>:</td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="password" required size="35"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">Confirm <font color="red">*</font>:</td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="cpassword" required size="35"></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The actual event handler is not returning anything, should be: `onsubmit="return validatePassword();"`

Comment: @Teemu thanks that worked. Didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler is currently not returning anything, use it like this:

```
onsubmit="return validatePassword();"
```